# Could not find or load main class Main using java -cp

Tags: java, classpath

I have a simple Java program

```
import java.sql.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String SQL_SELECT = "select * from accesspoint";
        try {
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:postgresql://192.168.1.2:19000/database",
                    "user",
                    "pass");
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(SQL_SELECT);
            ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }
}
```

and I build it using `javac Main.java`.
When I try to run it with `java Main` I get an obvious exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: 
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for 
jdbc:postgresql://192.168.1.2:19000/database
```

The question is how to fix it? I have postgresql-42.6.0.jar in the same directory, so I tried using java -cp but got an error:

```
$ java -cp "/home/mst/test_conn/postgresql-42.6.0.jar" Main
Error: Could not find or load main class Main
```

Also, I tried to set up the CLASSPATH variable and got the same error as above.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Put both the JDBC driver JAR and the directory what contains `Main.class` on your class path, separated by a colon (`:`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To specify the classpath, including the current directory (.) and the location of the PostgreSQL JDBC driver JAR file, use the -cp option with the java command. Execute the command as follows:

```
java -cp .:postgresql-42.6.0.jar Main
```

Comment: Addendum: For Windows, the separator is `;` instead of `:`